# does mysql stored procedures support data types like array, hash,etc?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

i am creating a mysql function which takes in a varchar and change it to a int based on a mapping table.

```
select name, convert_to_code(country) from users where sex = 'male'
```

here, the `convert_to_code()` function takes in a country name (e.g. Japan, Finland..) and change it to country code which is an integer (e.g. 1001, 2310..) based on a mapping table called `country_maping` like below:

```
country_name (varchar) | country_code (int)
Japan                  | 1001
Finland                | 2310
Canada                 | 8756
```

currently, the stored function need to `select country_code from country_mapping where country_name = country_name` and return the query result. is that possible to create a hash data struct in SP to optimize the process so that it will not need to perform the query for each row matches the `where` clause.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just use the table as you're doing.

If you create a covering index over those two columns, it should make it as efficient as possible.